# AWS SDK instance creation doesn't accept AMI ID

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-opsworks

I'm trying to perform instance creation through Node.js AWS SDK and I'm using following code for that:

```
OpsWorks.createInstanceAsync({
    InstanceType: config.instanceType,
    LayerIds: [config.layerId],
    StackId: config.stackId,
    RootDeviceType: params.RootDeviceType || 'ebs',
    AvailabilityZone: params.AvailabilityZone,
    InstanceType: params.InstanceType,
    SubnetId: params.SubnetId,
    AmiId: config.amiId
  });
});
```

This piece of code works fine when no AmiId is specified (booting completely new instance). In order to reduce deployment time, I planned to use AMI and when added AmiId parameter I'm getting following error:

```
ValidationException: The AMI ID cannot be set for this OS
```

Any ides why this happens on OpsWorks (Ubuntu 14.04)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the OS for the AMI. Use code below.

```
OpsWorks.createInstanceAsync({
    InstanceType: config.instanceType,
    LayerIds: [config.layerId],
    StackId: config.stackId,
    RootDeviceType: params.RootDeviceType || 'ebs',
    AvailabilityZone: params.AvailabilityZone,
    InstanceType: params.InstanceType,
    SubnetId: params.SubnetId,
    Os: 'Custom',
    AmiId: config.amiId
  });
});
```

Comment: It worked, thanks!!!   aws opsworks --region us-east-1 create-instance --stack-id ****** --layer-ids ***** --hostname ****** --instance-type c3.large --ami-id ***** --os "Custom"
{
    "InstanceId": "8c5c842b-d308-4e31-abcd-4ff671195bcd"
}